# Loopback error without strong-error-handler

Tags: node.js, loopback

If I have `strong-error-handler` in my `middleware.json` (i.e `"final": { "strong-error-handler": {} }`) then the error response structure looks like this:

```
{
  "error": {
      "statusCode": 500,
      "message": "Your Error Message",
      "code": "123"
  }
}
```

But when I remove `strong-error-handler` from `middleware.json`, then the error structure looks like this:

```
{
  "errors": [
     {
        "status": 500,
        "source": {},
        "title": "Error",
        "code": "123",
        "detail": "Your Error Message"
     }
  ]
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how/where that error body is made when I'm not using `strong-error-handler`. Is there a default?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!! Turns out it was using the errorHandler from `loopback-component-jsonapi` node module.